# How to compare latest two files are identical or not with shell?

Tags: shell

I wanna check whether the latest two files are different or not.
This is my code, it does not work.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x -e

function test() {
  ls ~/Downloads/* -t | head -n 2 | xargs cmp -s
  echo $?
}

test
```

Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the `function` keyword makes your code needlessly incompatible with POSIX sh (as compared to using extensions that actually add value); consider using the compliant syntax `funcname() { ... }` rather than `function funcname { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have GNU find and GNU sort:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^ - not /bin/sh, which lacks <()

{
  IFS= read -r -d '' file1
  IFS= read -r -d '' file2
} < <(find ~/Downloads -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -n -z)

if cmp -s -- "$file1" "$file2"; then
  echo "Files are identical"
else
  echo "Files differ"
fi
```

If your operating system is MacOS X and you have GNU `findutils` and `coreutils` installed through [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/), [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/), you might need to replace the `find` with `gfind` and the `sort` with `gsort` to get GNU rather than BSD implementations of these tools.

Key points here:

- `find` is asked to emit a stream in the form of `[epoch-timestamp] [filename][NULL]`. This is done because NUL is the only character that cannot exist in a pathname.
- `sort` is asked to sort this stream numerically.
- The first two items of the stream are read into shell variables.
- Using the `--` argument to `cmp` after options and before positional arguments ensures that filenames can never be parsed as positional arguments, even if the were to start with `-`.

---

So, why not use `ls -t`? Consider (as an example) what happens if you have a file created with the command `touch $'hello\nworld'`, with a literal newline partway through its name; depending on your version of `ls`, it may be emitted as `hello?world`, `hello^Mworld` or `hello\nworld` (in any of these cases, a filename that doesn't actually exist if treated as literal and not glob-expanded), or as two lines, `hello`, and `world`. This would mess up the rest of your pipeline (and things as simple as filenames with spaces will also break `xargs` with default options, as will filenames with literal quotes; `xargs` is only truly safe when used with the argument `-0` to treat content as NUL-delimited, though it's less unsafe than defaults when used with the GNU extension `-d $'\n'`).

See also:

- [ParsingLs ("Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- [BashFAQ #3 ("How can I find the latest (newest, earliest, oldest) file in a directory?")](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003)